# Update/configure and run a laravel project locally, after importing sql db?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.5, php-7.1

I got a git copy of a laravel project and the admin sent me an sql saying I'd need to import that and configure laravel to launch the project.

I've tried quite a few things for this like the instruction on `https://gist.github.com/hootlex/da59b91c628a6688ceb1` along with reinstalling composer and trying to upload the db to phpMyadmin but I still keep getting errors:

`composer install` gives

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In Connection.php line 664:
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'dbname' (SQL: select * from `system_configs`)

In PDOConnection.php line 50:
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'dbname'

In PDOConnection.php line 46:
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'dbname'

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

`composer.phar install` returns
    `Could not open input file: composer.phar`

`php artisan serve` gives

```
In Connection.php line 664:
      SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
       (SQL: select * from `system_configs`)
    In PDOConnection.php line 50:
      SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
    In PDOConnection.php line 46:
      SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

There is no `PDOConnection.php` and the `database.php` seems consistent with what I've seen on the web, along with my `.env` file.

I have a feeling I'm missing something really easy- how do you go about working in a git copy laravel project when you have to import an sql db that the admin says is key to executing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was with the db itself, not what I was doing; PDO is the PHP module laravel uses to communicate w/the db you use (SQL), so after I'd imported my db into a new table through PHPMyAdmin, laravel should be able to reach it no problem (the process goes: laravel -> PHP/PDO ->PHPMyAdmin ->DB).

I had to disable the foreign checks to do the import properly, and that solved the problem.